# Does a 5 on the Computer Dice count towards successes?

Tags: paranoia-2017

The Players Handbook says:

> When your character needs to do a non-easy thing in the game or the GM asks you
>   to do a thing, you’ll roll a number of dice equal to your NODE plus the Computer
>   Dice. You always roll the Computer Dice. Even if your NODE is zero or less, you
>   still roll the Computer Dice.
>
> Each rolled dice that shows a 5 or 6 is a ‘success’ and adds one point
>   to your final total. (p 24)

To be clear, does a 5 on the Computer Dice count towards a player's successes?

I do understand that I can rule either way as GM, and that I can choose to be inconsistent about it and punish the traitors who question it. I'm just curious if there is a clear answer or clarification somewhere that I am missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, a 5 counts as a success on the Computer Dice.

A Computer Dice (Die! Die!) is always rolled when you're doing things. The Computer Dice may also be the *only* dice rolled.  So when the rules say, *Each rolled dice that shows a 5 or 6 is a ‘success’* it is referring to all the dice the player rolls, which includes the Computer Dice and may indeed be *only* the Computer Dice.  However the phrase *Each of the dice rolled* will never refer to a pool of dice not including the Computer Dice.

This rule would also refer to any additional dice which are gained through other means, because again, it says *Each rolled dice*.  Which means each dice the player rolls.

There is also an example later on of what happens when you have a negative NODE (p. 26, emphasis mine):

> If your NODE dice number for a particular task is negative, treat the negative number as a positive and roll that many dice – plus the Computer dice, of course. However, any dice that don’t show 5 or 6 subtract from your score rather than simply not adding to it – so **if you rolled 4 dice and only 1 showed a 5 or 6**, then your overall score is 1 minus 3, making -2, which is a pretty bad score.

Here the rules state *if you rolled 4 dice and only 1 showed a 5 or 6.*  The Computer Dice was already mentioned as part of the calculation, so it's quite clear that the Computer Dice is included in the dice pool, and the rolling of 5 or 6 includes the Computer Dice.

There is never any indication that a Computer Dice is treated differently than the other dice, except when a computer is rolled.